# Turtle's bgpic() Function - Can't Read File

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am experimenting with various turtle functions, and I have recently come across the `bgpic()` function. It should be really simple, being able to set the background of my Turtle window to the chosen image.

My testing script is the following:

```py
import turtle
tu = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()

wn.bgpic("test.png")
```

Again, really simple, however when I attempt to run the program, the turtle window opens, but a bunch of errors show on the shell, a lot of which have to do with Python's internal coding it's self:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1481, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 478, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4103, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4048, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "test.png"
```

It most likely has a really simple fix, but I have done the mandatory searching on Google, and found nothing related to the issue. The file isn't corrupted, as I am still perfectly able to open it, any support would be really useful, thanks.

Comment: try with another png image. It can be that you downloaded an image that is not png but manually saved it with png extension. An image viewer might be smart enough to automatically detect the image format and display it regardless of the extension. Try with an image that you know 100% sure is png.

Answer (score 0):

.png formats don’t work with turtle.

You need to turn it into a gif file using an online image converter.